# How to specify a specific type of an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Carousel` that render either a card with data if there is data, or a skeleton when no data. I have this error :

```
Type 'EmptyElement' is not assignable to type 'Annonce | Annonce2'.
  Type 'EmptyElement' is missing the following properties from type 'Annonce2': ....
```

Here is my code :

```
if (biens.length) {
    return (
      <Carousel
        data={data}
        renderElement={(bien) => {
          if (bien.id === 'isEmptyMock') return <SkeletonCardDernierBien isEmptyMock />;

          return (
            <Component
              key={bien.id}
              annonce={bien}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

Here is my interface :

```
import { Annonce } from '.../Annonce/Annonce';
import { Annonce2 } from '.../Annonce2';

export type EmptyElement = {
  id: string;
};

export interface MyProps {
  biens: (Annonce | Annonce2 | EmptyElement)[];
}
```

How can i tell TypeScript that `if (bien.id === 'isEmptyMock')` type must be `EmptyElement`, and the rest when data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use discriminated unions to tell TypeScript what data / shape to expect.
Something like this:

```
type Annonce = {
  id: string
  otherField: string
}

type Annonce2 = {
  id: string
  yetAnotherField: string
}

export type Bien =
  | {
    status: 'empty'
    data: EmptyElement
  } |
  {
    status: 'filled'
    data: Annonce | Annonce2
  }
export type EmptyElement = {
  id: string;
};

export interface MyProps {
  biens: Bien[];
}
```

If you can set the status to empty or filled instead of the id to isEmptyMock this should work.

[This article](https://www.totaltypescript.com/discriminated-unions-are-a-devs-best-friend) by Matt Pocock gives more insight into discriminated unions.
[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQHZIPZIMbwLxwN6hxwCWAJgFxwDOYATsUgOaFypgAWMtAYsTADYVqdBsxABfUKEixEKdFgBMcXARBEylGvSYsIMMMjacefQVpG6JUkDAAeUVLTBwZ8AEJ8kKlgB98LEQ0AIZgAK5UlADkMAC2UJBRgXCkocGUAKLxkBn8cTBIYCzicL4sakRBYKER0QBmxPx5pEnqlanVlMhomPD%203QowisWg9o7OrtDwWQkQufmFKgFtmsI6jADcoOJbIKMOTi4MYFx1wVhwALIQAAq0qFBUy0QARl6RcJ4FANoAurviIA)